# Type of dialogues?

Tags: dialogue

I was writing a short story about characters. I have a problem with the dialogue style I wrote it in. It is like this:

> **Karan:** Hey Piyush! How are you?
> **Piyush:** Hey, I'm good. What about you?
> **Karan:** I am fine. So in which company are you working?
> **Piyush:** I am working with Concentrix.
> **Karan:** What is your post?
> **Piyush:** I am in the security department.
> **Karan:** That's great!
> **Piyush:** Not that great.
> **Karan:** Why so?
> **Piyush:** I am not that happy with this post.
> **Karan:** Which is the perfect post for you?
> **Piyush:** I like manager post than security.
> **Karan:** Why don't you try in some other company?
> **Piyush:** I am planning to do that.

Some people advised me to change it. So, I am asking/looking for a style that simple, good for the story, and easy to understand. Are there names for styles of dialogues?

Comment: Are you asking for a critique/review of the text of your dialogue? If so, that's [off topic](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If not, can you clarify? I don't know what you mean by "styles of dialogue".

Comment: https://www.englishbix.com/types-of-dialogues-with-examples/ Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you asking how to punctuate dialog? There are lots of references on the usual style in English, using quotation marks, e.g. [this](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/style-and-usage/how-to-punctuate-dialogue.html). Another style is using em dashes, but that's commoner in French than English. Or are you interested in something else?

Comment: I'm talking here about dialogue not punctuate. @Lea, give me good a site to start with.

Comment: Do you mean like play (this) versus prose?